# Finding quickest way around a circle?

Tags: geometry

So say I have two lines going from the radius to the edge, one of these is my start point and the other is the end point. I need to find out which direction I should rotate them in to get to the end point fastest. (this will be done through a while loop adding and subtracting 1). For example say we have StartRotation = 45 and EndRotation = 270, I need the math algorithm to find out whether to add our subtract (in the examples case we will subtract because going counter clockwise around a circle from 45 degrees to 270 degrees is faster than going clock wise).

(A Side note: setting the rotation to -90, 630, etc... is the same as setting it to 270)

Answer (score 1):

Possible logic:

```
Normalize angles

if Start < End
   Direction = 1
else
   Direction =  - 1

if Abs(Start - End) > 180
   Direction = - Direction
```

Answer (score 0):

The two angles are |S-E| and 360°-|S-E|. Keep the smallest.

```
D= S - E
if D > 0:
  if D > 180:
    D-= 360
else:
  if D < -180:
    D+= 360
```

`D` gives the signed amplitude.